# I am trying to create a registration form to add data to 2 tables simultaneously. But I am not sure what to write after the POST method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

> I want to create a user into auth_user. And use its id(primary key) to
>   fill in an entry into User_Profile to take it as a Foreign key.

**Models.py:**

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Profile
        fields = [ 'contact_number', 'birth_date', 'address', 'role']
```

**Views.py:**

```
def registration_view(request):

    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST)



else:
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2
    }
    return render(request, 'Schoool/registration_form.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! 
I had one more query, what if I wanted to put a drop-down for the role field and let's consider that 'role' in UserProfile table is a foreign-key from the table 'Role'.

Comment: Okay, I got it. It does that on its own!